# ScrollView can host only one direct child and i also have only one child

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a layout which need to be scrollable.This is a fragment and the fragment hosted on a activity.The ScrollView has only one child which is relativeLayout and the relativeLayout has multiple child.But i still get the error.The error occured when i install and open the screen,after 5 or 6 second,the app is crashed.
This is my layout structure for fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable"/>

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/settingsAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                >

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                      
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                         />

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/backButton"
                        style="@style/back_arrow_button"
                       />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView     
               >
                <LinearLayout
            
                   
                   >

                    <RelativeLayout style="@style/settings_relative_layout_style">
                        <TextView
                          />
                        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView               
                           />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/settings_text_style"
 />

                    <RelativeLayout style="@style/settings_relative_layout_style">

                        <TextView
                         />

                        <ImageView
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout style="@style/settings_relative_layout_style">

                        <TextView
                            
                           />

                        <ImageView
                            
                         />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <View
                       
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        
                       />

                    <RelativeLayout style="@style/settings_relative_layout_style">

                        <TextView
                         
                            />

                        <ImageView
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout style="@style/settings_relative_layout_style">

                        <TextView
                            
                            />

                        <ImageView
                            />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout style="@style/settings_relative_layout_style">

                        <TextView                        
                           />
                        <ImageView
                        />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout style="@style/settings_relative_layout_style">

                        <TextView           
                         />

                        <ImageView
                            style="@style/settings_image_view_style"
                           />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

This is the layout for Main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.presentations.activity.MainActivity">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomMenu"
            app:defaultNavHost="true" />

        <me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:iconSize="@dimen/l"
            android:elevation="@dimen/xxxs"
            app:iconTintActive="@color/nav_icon_color"
            app:iconTint="#D0D0D0"
            android:id="@+id/bottomMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/xxxxxxl"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

The error msg:

`FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: ltd.tinkers.example, PID: 10147 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.addView(NestedScrollView.java:515) at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar$SnackbarBaseLayout.addToTargetParent(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:1330) at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar.showView(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:757) at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar$1.handleMessage(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:263) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:603) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)`

I try to use NestedScrollView but problem not fix.I wrap the fragment layout scroll view with FrameLayout which is found from stack overflow answer.But this did not work.

Comment: Based on the error message, it appears as though you are trying to show a `Snackbar`. Do you have any code related to that?

Comment: The Snackbar is on BaseFragment class.The Base Fragment extend the Fragment() class and the BaseFragment class extend by all class for creating fragment in my project..But i do not call for show the snackBar

Comment: The XML for the fragment layout is wrong. In the first `RelativeLayout` tag the attribute `android:background="@drawable/>` misses a closing double quote while the slash shouldn't be there.

Comment: Actually i post the code for understand the hierarchy.This problem is not about syntax error. in my original code there is no double quote missing.this is my typing mistake for this post.I will edit this